# Open Redirects - Can they be done without modifying server side code?

Tags: url-redirection

Open redirects showed up in the news this week thanks to Microsoft.  While this is very old issue, this is a new topic for me.  The concern seems to be that a user hovering over a link may not read beyond the domain name.  In the following example, the user reads as far as example.com, and assumes the domain is safe, without reading the parameters.

I.e., `example.com/?some_redirect_param=evil.com.`

All of the examples I have seen require some kind of redirection code outside of the browser.  I.e., a user clicks on link to example.com.  The request is sent to example.com and example.com uses the redirect parameter to evil.com and forwards the user to evil.com.

This makes the problem sound primarily about securing your servers/proxies from hackers.  Am I missing something?  Can this be done entirely client side say in an email aside from using an OnClick JavaScript event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This makes the problem sound primarily about securing your servers/proxies from hackers

Open redirects are not something hackers create, but these are a vulnerability in the server side web application which hackers can exploit. So it is not about *securing* servers from hackers but about *fixing* the vulnerability, so it cannot be exploited in the first place.

> Can this be done entirely client side say in an email aside from using an OnClick JavaScript event?

An open redirect means that the client is visiting the given URL at the server but that the server then redirects the client to some other (attackers) site. This way the attacker can exploit the trust into the original server to make the client visit a malicious site. Thus it always involves a server issuing the redirect.

There are client-only ways to trick the client into thinking, that a different URL is visited than what is actually visited - like hijacking the link click with Javascript. But these are different kind of problems, not open redirects.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that it's taking advantage of server side vulnerabilities.  That is something I have tested for before and found weaknesses in.  I just didn't realize what it was called.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be done entirely client side say in an email aside from using an OnClick JavaScript event?

Yes, it can be done client-side (though probably not in email). Although the classic open redirect is a server-side vulnerability where the server parses user input in the request and issues a redirect to an unrelated site in the response, you can also have open redirect through client-side scripts. Consider a login form (the usual place to find open redirect) where rather than submitting an HTML form (containing the redirect URL) to the server and the server responding with a 3xx to the specified URL, the user's credentials are sent to the server using a script-initiated background request (XHR/fetch) and if the server accepts them, the client-side script (still running on the login page; no navigation has occurred yet) parses the redirect out of the URL (possibly out of the URL *fragment*, which never gets sent to the server anyhow) and sets `location.href`.

This is, to be clear, still a web application vulnerability. It's not a situation that the attacker creates, merely one where they find and exploit a vuln. The *fix* still requires a server-side change - modifying the client scripts that the server serves to the browser - but the attack doesn't require any server-side access; as in "classic" open redirects, you're attacking the user rather than the server (but yes, *via* a security bug in the server).

Note that approximately no email system lets script in the email execute; this would be an extremely major vulnerability in basically all cases. However, an email (or SMS, or Slack message, or post on StackExchange, or...) might contain a link to a webpage which contains an open redirect vulnerability, and the link might contain an exploit for that vulnerability.

---

A very close analogy from cross-site scripting: classic open redirects are like reflected XSS (where the user unwittingly sends some input to the server that modifies the server response in an attacker-chosen way), whereas client-side open redirects are like DOM-based XSS (where the server serves vulnerable javascript which consumes user data and does something unsafe with it, taking an attacker-chosen action without the server necessarily seeing the user input at all).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify things for me.